# php edit button better as a form or href link?

Tags: php, html, forms, performance

I'm just curious what is the better method for edit buttons in an admin, keeping in mind the there could possible be 100s of these edit buttons on a page,

a form to use the POST variables

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="123" />
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="ABC" />
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" class="edit></button>
```

or a href to use the GET variables

```
<a href="?action=Edit&ID=123&Name=ABC" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

I'm just curious in regards to speed and usability. 
Any opinions welcome.

Comment: Because you are not posting data (updating data in fact), this is something that should be done by a GET.

Comment: I always go with  edit button as a form, with some sort of validation at server side,that if anybody change id or name it validates that values are legal and correct for editing or not?

Comment: depends on the number of fields you have.

Comment: My thought here was to try and avoid admins editing pages they didn't want to by clicking on links in browser history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server Side**

Edit button or form button do not impact server side processing at all.

If you are looking to reduce the html file size , the get variable based approach could help and reduce that less than 5% extra overhead (can vary based on type of application).

**Client Side**

The % impact on client side will also be negligible based on how browser handles the submit action.

**Side Notes**

- href links work only as a replacement for GET forms and not for POST.
- url based approach is useful in cases like edit button where there is no user modified input

Comment: Thanks arkoak, that makes it very clear, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Even better is using the HTTP [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method which meant to represent partial resource modification.

You should avoid using `GET` requests when the outcome alters a resource (because the request will be resent by hitting the back button).

However since many browsers cannot send native PATCH requests you need a bit of trickery. Ruby On Rails for example uses javascript together with a `method` `POST` parameter to fake `PATCH`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests - even on links.